# Only Status bar Transparent, not a Navigation bar

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I want to set a transparent status bar, not a navigation bar.

what I tried

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

But it set Status bar and navigation bar both transparent. I want only Status bar transparent

I also want to set different status bar color based on Fragment, And my navigation drawer is an overriding status bar, like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

And in your layout you want to have a transparent status bar, set below attribute:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Lolipop and above:

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent)
```

And on Marshmallow and above for transparent status with dark icons

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

or transparent status with light icons

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
```